# Share socks5 connection to a 2nd NIC system wide

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks, hostapd

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

I have a server with two NICs. 
One is wireless (wlan0) made as an access point (using hostapd) and the other one (eth0) is connected to a network that doesn't have access to the internet. What has instead, is a free access to a remote ssh server.
If I use a dynamic port while SSH-ing to that server, I can get internet access on this machine. I can use proxychains to do most of the access to the internet (because the dynamic ssh link is a SOCKS5 connection).

Now, would it be possible to use redsocks to have anyone connectinng to the access point, getting internet connection, if I establish in advance, this dynamic ssh connection over eth0?